# Box2d body fixture several times too large when using PhysicsEditor

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I'm using the PhysicsEditor tool to export a compound shape for box2d. I've second-checked everything I can think of - but the collision shapes are coming out several times larger than the sprite shape.

The ptm_ratio values are correct, the class that loads these [GB2ShapeCache](https://github.com/CodeAndWeb/GBox2D/blob/master/GBox2D/GB2ShapeCache.mm) is applying the `ptm_ratio` properly to the vertex coords, I've made the anchorpoint is set to the middle, just like cocos2d.

No matter what the ptm ratio is, the bounding box is usually several times larger than the sprite. As if the sprite size was multiplied by 5. I've tried this for two different sprites and I see the same result.

Any ideas?

```
<key>asteroid-small</key>
<dict>
  <key>anchorpoint</key>
          <string>{ 0.5000,0.5000 }</string>
  <key>fixtures</key>
  <array>

    <dict>
                  <key>density</key> <real>10</real>
                  <key>friction</key> <real>0.1</real>
                  <key>restitution</key> <real>0.1</real>
                  <key>filter_categoryBits</key> <integer>1</integer>
                  <key>filter_groupIndex</key> <integer>0</integer>
                  <key>filter_maskBits</key> <integer>65535</integer>
                  <key>isSensor</key> <false/>
                  <key>id</key> <string></string>
                  <key>fixture_type</key> <string>POLYGON</string>

      <key>polygons</key>
      <array>
        <array> 
          <string>{ -13.000,10.500 }</string> 
          <string>{ -14.000,5.500 }</string>  
          <string>{ -13.000,-6.500 }</string> 
          <string>{ 7.000,-13.500 }</string>  
          <string>{ 16.000,-5.500 }</string>  
          <string>{ 16.000,2.500 }</string> 
          <string>{ 10.000,13.500 }</string>  
          <string>{ -3.000,12.500 }</string>
        </array>
        <array> 
          <string>{ -8.000,-17.500 }</string> 
          <string>{ -2.000,-17.500 }</string> 
          <string>{ 7.000,-13.500 }</string>  
          <string>{ -13.000,-6.500 }</string> 
          <string>{ -13.000,-12.500 }</string>
        </array>
        <array> 
          <string>{ 1.000,17.500 }</string> 
          <string>{ -3.000,12.500 }</string>  
          <string>{ 10.000,13.500 }</string>  
          <string>{ 5.000,17.500 }</string>
        </array>
        <array> 
          <string>{ -13.000,-6.500 }</string> 
          <string>{ -14.000,5.500 }</string>  
          <string>{ -16.000,3.500 }</string>  
          <string>{ -16.000,-1.500 }</string>
        </array>
      </array>
    </dict>
```

Comment: did you use the retina or standard images in PE? I believe you have to use the standard resolution images in PE.

Comment: Standard. I don't know what I did to fix it, but it seems like choosing the "single frame" mode in the auto-select tool seems to solve the problem. I also realized I wasn't syncing my sprite with the box2d body rotation, so the body would rotate but the sprite would not, explaining some weird is/isn't working problems I saw. Seems to be fully fixed so far.